# Creating CLOB in OCCI for inserting into database

Tags: c++, oracle10g, clob, occi

I have some large data objects that have been serialized into a string/ostringstream using Boost.
I would like to store these serialized objects in the database with the datatype CLOB via a procedure. In order to do so I am creating a CLOB-object but I don't know how to "put my data into the CLOB(myClob)".

I have seen some examples but all of them uses char-pointers and I would prefer not going down that alley...

Below is my c++ code so far. If you have any examples or good tips/links I would really appreciate any help.

Thx in advance

```
string qOracleDb::testRunStoredProc(const string& xId, const qTime date, const string& xUsage, int type, const std::ostringstream& data)
{   
    try
    {
        Clob myClob;
        myClob.setEmpty();

        myClob ?????

        myStmt=myConn->createStatement("BEGIN DATA.SAVE_DATA_TEMP( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5); END;");

        Date asofDate(myEnv, date.year(), date.month(), date.day(),0,0,0);
        myStmt->setDate(1, asofDate);
        myStmt->setString(2,xId);
        myStmt->setString(3,xUsage);
        myStmt->setInt(4, type);
        myStmt->setClob(5, myClob);

        myStmt->execute();      
    }

    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        // close nicely
        myConn->terminateStatement (myStmt);
        return "Exception thrown : "+ ex.getMessage()+", " + qStringUtils::toString(ex.getErrorCode());
    }
    // close nicely
    myConn->terminateStatement (myStmt);
    return "succes";
}
```

UPDATE: Since I have found code examples that have solved my problems I would like to share the solution since somebody else might also face this "challenge" one day. 
My data-variable has changed from a stream to a string and my code is as below:

```
/* Create dummy-clob in DB and insert data */
    myStmt = myConn->createStatement("begin dbms_lob.createtemporary(:p1,FALSE);end;");
    myStmt->registerOutParam(1,OCCICLOB);
    myStmt->executeUpdate();

    Clob resClob = myStmt->getClob(1);
    resClob.write((unsigned int)data.size(), (unsigned char*)data.c_str(),(unsigned int)data.size());
    myConn->terminateStatement (myStmt);


    myStmt=myConn->createStatement("BEGIN DATA.SAVE_NOUVO_DATA( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5); END;");

    Date asofDate(myEnv, date.year(), date.month(), date.day(),0,0,0);
    myStmt->setDate(1, asofDate);
    myStmt->setString(2,xId);
    myStmt->setString(3,xUsage);
    myStmt->setInt(4, type);
    myStmt->setClob(5, resClob);

    myStmt->execute();
```